# access violation when when writing to files

Tags: c#, asynchronous, io, file-writing, hololens

I am writing multiple files at the same time in c#.
I am composing videos of multiple photos and saving them asyncronously in files in the same folder.
It can happen that there could be 2-3 savings at the same time. 
Sometimes after a few savings the program crashes and i get:

> The program '...' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005)
>   'Access violation'.

```
 if (images % framesPerIO == 0 )
        {
            MediaComposition clone = composition.Clone();
            int videoNumber = images / framesPerIO;
            Debug.WriteLine("Reseting clip from" +videoNumber.ToString());
            composition = new MediaComposition();
            CreateVideo(videoNumber, clone);     
        }

private async Task CreateVideo(int videoNumber, MediaComposition clone)
    {


        Debug.WriteLine("Creating xml"+videoNumber.ToString());
            StorageFile video = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("video" + videoNumber.ToString() + ".xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            Debug.WriteLine("xml Created" + videoNumber.ToString());


            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            Debug.WriteLine("SavingAsync XML " + video.DisplayName);
            await clips.SaveAsync(video);
            Debug.WriteLine("SavedAsync "+video.DisplayName + (DateTime.Now - now).ToString());


    }
```

Now, I have 2 questions:

1. Can i do a breakpoint to see to find out where in the code does
   the problem happens?
2. Can it be that the access violation happens
   because there is no consecutive memory on disk, since another thread
   starts creating a new file? If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: Debugging likely won't help since concurrent events like the one you're describing wouldn't happen while debugging. You could try exclusively locking the area of code that does the writes, or putting write commands in a queue and having a single thread write them sequentially.

Comment: @Tudor Would that affect performance, because the reason i am doing them in parallel is because the performance critical?

Comment: @bommelding No, it is a little simplified, but if i use await the execution stops until i do the writing. I cannot create a new composition of the photos when I am writing the file

Comment: @Tudor I know Debugging likely won't help since concurrent events like the one you're describing wouldn't happen while debugging. I just want to break where the problem happens to confirm that the access violation happens because of the file writing and not somewhere else in the code

Comment: Is your disk mechanical or solid-state? If it's mechanical it might actually improve performance if you write your files sequentially.

Comment: @Tudor I am using hololens, and i have not found what type of storage does it use. I read someplace it was flash memory. Can you help me make it in a queue?